# 2008 Vw Jetta won't move? Transmission issue!! Help

Tags: transmission, vw

I have a 2008 Vw Jetta 2.5l. On the way to work this morning I stopped at a stop sign and when I took off I heard a clunk and had to coast off the road. It is an automatic transmission and I can put it into any gear R, D, Sport and it will not move just revs up. It will not engage in any of them. Anyone know the issue? Thanks

Comment: Does the speedo move when you Rev it up in drive?  Keep your foot on the brake while you do this, just in case it starts to work again.

Comment: If you put the transmission lever into park, does it keep the car from going any place (keeps it from rolling)?